# How to optimize (fewer cyclings) a specific while loop in r

Tags: r, while-loop

I'm trying to check if any value in the 1st column of a2 matches any value in the 1st column of m_. If there is, extract that row with that value from a2. Finally merge all the qualified rows together.

```
i=1

while(i<149473)
{j=1
while(j<10249){
if(as.integer(a2[i,1])==as.integer(m_[j,1])){
ob<-rbind(ob,a2[i,])
}  
j=j+1}
i=i+1
}
return(ob)
```

It's so time consuming to get the result because the large amount of rows in the data frames.. 
Can anybody help me optimize the loop?

Comment: I guess you need to check the documentation for the `match` function

Comment: ... or the `merge` function

Comment: What are you trying to do. You are deep within second circle of http://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf - it appears you are looking to merge two data frames on the first column but as your haven't provided a reproducible example or explained what you are trying to do it is impossible to help.\

Comment: I'm trying to check if any value in the 1st column of a2 matches any value in the 1st column of m_. If there is, extract that row with that value from a2. Finally merge all the qualified rows together. @mnel

Comment: Edit your question and include a description there. I still have no idea why you are using a loop, let alone nested loops.

Comment: It's the only way i can think of. I know it's too basic. I do not know if there is any function in r can do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something as simple as

```
ob <- a2[a2[[1]] %in% unique(m[[1]]),]
```

Comment: Thank you. think I need dig deep in R